# Name spaces in c++ and c

Tags: c++, c, syntax

Not that I would *ever* write the code like the following in my professional work, the following code is legal and compiles without warnings in c++ and c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foo { int foo; } foo;

foo * alloc_foo () {
   return (struct foo*) malloc(sizeof(foo));
}   

struct foo * alloc_struct_foo () {
   return (foo*) malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
}   


foo * make_foo1 (int val) {
   foo * foo = alloc_struct_foo (); 
   foo->foo = 0;
   return foo;
}

struct foo * make_foo2 (int val) {
   struct foo * foo = alloc_foo();
   foo->foo = 0;
   return foo;
}
```

What makes this legal and unambiguous in C is section 6.2.3 of the C standard:

> 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers
>   If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers (label names; tags of structures, unions, and enumerations; members of structures or unions; and ordinary identifiers).

Note that thanks to label names living in their own name spaces, I could have made the code even more obfuscated by using a label `foo` somewhere.

Add the following and the code does not compile:

```
int foo (foo * ptr) {
   return ++ptr->foo;
}
```

So, two questions, one related to C and C++ and the other, C++.

- C/C++ question: Why can't I define the function `foo`?
  It seems I should be able to define the function `foo`; function names and variable names are "ordinary identifiers". But if I add that last little bit of code I get `error: redefinition of 'foo' as different kind of symbol`.
  Question: `foo * foo;` is perfectly legal, so why isn't `int foo (foo*);` legal?
- C++ question: How does this work at all in C++?
  The meaning of "name space" takes on a rather different meaning on in C++ than in C. I can't find anything in the C++ standard that talks about the C concept of name spaces, which is what makes the above legal in C.
  Question: What makes this legal in C++ (chapter and verse preferred)?

Comment: "Why can I define the function foo in C++?" - Can you??

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Yes, I can. Try it. Both `g++ -Wall -c -DFOO foo.cc` and `clang -Wall -c -DFOO foo.cc` compile without warnings. Whether this is just a fluke of those two compilers, I don't know. Hence C++ question #2.

Comment: Are you defining `cplusplus`?

Comment: "Why can't I define the function foo?" My guess would be that a variable named foo and a function named foo would cause issues since you can use a function name as a function pointer.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Stupid me! I'll modify the question.

Comment: @jswolf19: The complaint is about a collision between the typedef name `foo` and the function `foo`. Note that the only places I am using `foo` as a variable name are local variables inside a function.

Comment: Consider what makes _illegal_, not what makes things legal.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: What makes *illegal* is question #1. Since function names and structure names live in different name spaces, where's the conflict? (There certainly is no conflict for `foo * foo;`.) What makes this legal at all in C++ is question #2.

Comment: @David: Yes, I read the question, thanks.

Comment: "Since function names and typedef names live in different name spaces" Prove it.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: That was a typo. Function names and structure names live in different name spaces in C. Where do they live in C++?

Comment: @David: The structure name is `struct foo`. Prove that the typedef name `foo` and the function name `foo` live in different name spaces.

Comment: ah, so you just can't call the function foo from within a function that defines a variable foo. Having a type and a function of the same name could cause problems with type casting syntax, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `foo * foo;` is perfectly legal, so why isn't int `foo (foo*);` legal?

Because there already is a type named `foo` in the same declaration context as your function. You cannot have a type and a function of the same name in the same scope.

> How does this work at all in C++?

Because you are allowed to hide names in nested scopes. When you declare `foo * foo`, the first `foo` refers to the type. The second `foo` declares a variable -- at that point, the type `foo` is hidden. Try declaring `foo * baz` after `foo * foo`, it should fail.

```
struct foo {};

void test() {
   foo * foo; // first `foo` is the type, second `foo` is the variable
   foo * baz; // first `foo` is the variable
}
```

Comment: *Because you are allowed to hide names in nested scopes.* This explains why this works in C++. And `foo * foo; foo * baz;` does fail. (And it fails in C as well.)

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 3.3.1/4 says that in a declarative region all declarations of a name must refer to the same entity (or an overload set). There's an exception that allows you to use a class name for a set of function names (so `foo()` hides `class foo`) but this doesn't apply if you have a typedef (which you do).

Try it with the `typedef struct foo foo` omitted in C++.

Comment: +1: Omitting the typedef does indeed let me define that function, once again thanks to being allowed to hide names in nested scopes in C++.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in C++ either ... the problem is that the pre-processor for gcc/g++ is looking for `__cplusplus`, not `cplusplus`.  Therefore you pre-processor statements

```
#if defined FOO && ! defined cplusplus
#undef FOO
#endif
```

do not work correctly.

Comment: You're right; I should have used `__cplusplus`. I modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is already function `foo()` it's a default constructof for `struct foo`

```
typedef struct foo 
{ 
int a; 
foo(int val)
:a(val) 
{}
} foo;


int foo(int value)
{
  cout << value <<endl;
}

void main()
{
   foo foovar = foo(50); // constructor foo or function foo?
}
```

There are no such things as constructors in C.

Edit specially for Alan Stokes:

```
typedef struct foo
    { 
    int a; 
    foo(int val, double val2)
    :a(val) 
    {
      cout << val2 << endl;
    }
    } foo;


    int foo(int value, double val2)
    {
      cout << value << val2 << endl;
    }

    void main()
    {
       some_random_func(foo(50, 1.0)); // constructor foo or function foo?
    }
```

Comment: Definitely not. For one, constructors don't have names and can't be found by name lookup.

Comment: how so? what about constructor overloading? foo(); foo(int); foo(double); ? Do you actually understand how overloading works?

Comment: `foo(50)` is technically not calling the constructor. It's an "explicit type conversion in the functional notation", and that `foo` is the name of the type not of the constructor.

Comment: @Alan Sokes oh yes? what about `Complex(5, 5);`? that's type conversion too?

Comment: @GreenScape, it's not. It's not a call either, even though it will cause the *unnamed* constructor to be called.

Comment: @GreenScape Yes. See 5.2.3/1. "A simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by a parenthesized expression-list
constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list." Try your example without the typedef; the function name then hides the class name.

Comment: @GreenScape: *Because there is already function foo() it's a default constructor for struct foo.* No there isn't. There is already a function `foo::foo()` that is the default constructor for `struct foo`. Having a separate function `foo()` is perfectly OK. The problem with defining `foo()` is the `typedef struct foo foo;` statement. Remove that typedef (in C++) and you can define both `foo()` and `foo::foo()`.

Comment: @DavidHammen, don't be fooled. `foo::foo` is not a function (in fact, it is a type, the *injected-class-name*). Constructors don't have names.

Comment: @avakar how would compiler export constructor into shared object so later user can load it if constructors have no names?

Comment: @avakar: I've never liked that statement in the standard "*Constructors do not have names.*" Well of course they have names. The compiler gives them a name, the linker binds the references to that name to the implementation of that name. That name is implementation-defined and is hidden. What they should have said is "Constructors do not have usable names. [*Note*: C++ code cannot explicitly call a constructor.]"

Comment: @GreenScape, ask your compiler vendor. Note however that symbols in your object files have nothing to do with C++ name lookup. By the way, up to three chunks of code will typically be generated by the compiler for each constructor, each associated with a different symbol. There isn't one-to-one correspondence between C++ names and symbol names.

Comment: @GreenScape: The phrase "*Constructors don't have names*" has two meanings; one for programmers and another for compilers. What this means to a programmer is that you cannot directly call a constructor in your code. What this means to a compiler vendor is that whatever internal names they do give to some constructor, those internal names must not ever conflict with the internal name(s) given to some valid C++ name.

Comment: @David Hammen what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608943/what-does-the-hides-constructor-for-warning-mean-when-compiling-valid-c-with? it's only possible to hide something that '''have''' name, right?

Comment: @GreenScape: g++ is issuing the wrong warning in that question. The constructor isn't being hidden. It is the entire type that is being -- and types do have names.

Comment: @David Hammen i suppose this is bug in GCC? Issuing wrong warning is a bugged behaviour, right?

Comment: @GreenScape: It depends on how the condition is caught. If g++ truly is detecting it as a collision between a function `foo()` and the default constructor for class `foo`, then it is a bug. If the detection is between the type name and function name, the suboptimal report is a misfeature rather than a bug.