# What does the 'hides constructor for' warning mean when compiling C++ with g++?

Tags: c++, g++

Using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct my_struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        my_struct();
};

my_struct::my_struct(void)
{
        printf("constructor\n");
}

void my_struct(void)
{
        printf("standard function\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct my_struct s;
        s.a = 1;
        s.b = 2;

        printf("%d-%d\n", s.a, s.b);

        return 0;
}
```

I get a warning compiling with g++ -Wshadow main.cpp:

```
main.cpp:15:20: warning: ‘void my_struct()’ hides constructor for ‘struct my_struct’
```

I would be ok with that warning if the void my_struct function actually replaced the my_struct::my_struct one. But it does not appears to be the case. If I run the program, I get:

```
constructor
1-2
```

Any idea what this warning mean ? It is quite annoying especially when I include C headers into C++ code

Comment: Why are you claiming that this is "valid C"?

Comment: You're right, the 'valid' word is a bit misleading. What I meant is that having struct my_struct {}; and void my_struct(); is completely valid in normal C and I did not understand why it caused a warning when compiled as C++. I just edited the title to remove the 'valid'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning points out that the `my_struct()` function has the same name as the `my_struct` structure. It means you will be unable to write:

```
my_struct s;         // Error.
```

Because the compiler will think that you're using a function as a type. However, as you probably realized, you can still instantiate your structure with the `struct` keyword:

```
struct my_struct s;  // Valid.
```

Comment: For another example, `my_struct();` is now a call to the function, whereas without the shadowing it would construct a temporary.

Comment: ok, I understand now, thanks. I missed some background about how instantiation is made in C++. Now an extra question. How can I get rid of this warning if I want to include C headers that have these kinds of name clashes but still want to compile with -Wshadow for the other parts of the code. 

Is it possible ?

Comment: @mbonnin, apart from renaming your structs/functions to avoid name clashes, or temporarily disabling `-Wshadow` with `#pragma` when including the headers, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: the #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow" works fine with gcc 4.5.1.Sounds like a reasonnable tradeoff to me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`void my_struct(void)` has the same name of your class/struct and since it is in the global namespace it is conflicting with your class/struct's constructor.

You could try something like:

```
#include <cstdio>


struct my_struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        my_struct();
};

my_struct::my_struct(void)
{
        printf("constructor\n");
}
namespace mbonnin
{
 void my_struct(void);
}

void mbonnin::my_struct(void)
 {
         printf("standard function\n");
 }

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        my_struct s;
        s.a = 1;
        s.b = 2;

        printf("%d-%d\n", s.a, s.b);
        mbonnin::my_struct();

return 0;
}
```

And by the way the `struct` in `struct my_struct s;` is redundant in C++.

Comment: "by the way the struct in struct my_struct s; is redundant in C++" - not in the questioner's case, where there's a function of the same name as the class.

Answer (score 0):

> `warning: ‘void my_struct()’ hides constructor for ‘struct my_struct’`
>   Any idea what this warning mean ?

It means that sometimes the warnings issued by the GNU compiler suite are a bit off. (Try omitting the semicolon after the close brace on the definition of `struct my_struct`. If you are using anything but a very recent version of g++ the error message will be a bit off.)

Something is being hidden here, but it is not the constructor for `struct my_struct`. What is being hidden is the name `my_struct` as a type identifier. You can see this in action if you remove the `struct` from the declaration of the variable `s`: Use `my_struct s;` instead of `struct my_struct s;` Without the contextual information offered by the `struct` keyword, the compiler now must interpret `my_struct` as a function name.